# saving data array causes crash swift

Tags: swift, userdefaults

I tried adding an item to an arrar and saving in Userdefault but the app crashed and I would love anyone to point me to what I am doing wrong

```
private func putArray(_ value: GMSAutocompletePrediction?, forKey key: String) {
        guard let value = value else {
            return
        }
        log("THE MESSAGE \(value)", .fuck)
        var newArray = getArray(forKey: key)
        log("THE MESSAGE ARRAY \(newArray)", .fuck)
        if newArray.contains(value) {
            newArray.remove(at: newArray.firstIndex(of: value)!)
        } else {
            newArray.append(value)
        }

        storage.setValue(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: newArray), forKey: key)
    }
```

error from crash

> [GMSAutocompletePrediction encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2818f9ce0
>   2019-09-26 13:40:07.300856+0100 MAX.NG Staging Debug[4440:1410011] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[GMSAutocompletePrediction encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2818f9ce0'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GMSAutocompletePrediction` doesn't conform to `NSCoding` so you can't save it to user defaults  , you may extract important details from it and make a custom model to save

Comment: but I am converting it to data before saving

Comment: is there no way I can make it conform to NSCoding?

Comment: for sorry no the properties are get only you can't even conform and set them

Comment: Okay, can I use it like this?

Comment: `struct LocalGMSAutocompletePrediction {
    var autoComplete: GMSAutocompletePrediction?
}`

Comment: what in terms of properties you need from this class saving ?

Comment: name and service id

Comment: `struct Root :Codable{ let name: String ; let serviceId:Int }` fill it from `GMSAutocompletePrediction` class and save it with `Codable`